# How to display .pgm image in iOS UIImageview?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a `.pgm` format image and i want to display it in iOS `UIImageView`.

I have tried putting the `image` in `UIImageView` but it is not displaying anything.

Are we not supposed to use `.pgm` format?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think below images file extension is readable in iPhone

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

[image]

Comment: yeah that i know but is there any way by which we can read the data or bytes of the .pgm format and display it on UIImageView

Comment: Then why are you directly trying to display it in the `UiImageView`? Read the data from it, convert it to another format & finally display it via a `UiImageView`.